# Sorting array in PHP containing word and number

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in PHP containing word "Paying" and years like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2014
    [1] => 'Paying'
    [2] => 2013
    [3] => 2015 
)
```

I want to short it so the "Paying" will always be the first following by descending order of years

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'Paying'
    [1] => 2015
    [2] => 2014
    [3] => 2013
)
```

What is the simple way to do it in php? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or do you expect that we just write your code?

Comment: play with the "value" sort functions: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here i simple use [`rsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php))

```
<?php

    $arr = array(2014, "Paying", 2013, 2015);

    print_r($arr);
    rsort($arr, SORT_STRING);
    print_r($arr);

?>
```

Output:

```
//Before
Array ( [0] => 2014 [1] => Paying [2] => 2013 [3] => 2015 )

//After
Array ( [0] => Paying [1] => 2015 [2] => 2014 [3] => 2013 )
```

Comment: Sorry, I just have time to check. This is not solving my problem yet.
The array is produced from sheetNames of an excel file.

`$sheetNames = $objPHPExcel['sitelist']->getSheetNames();
print_r($sheetNames);`

output:

`Array ( [0] => 2014 [1] => Paying [2] => 2013 [3] => 2015 )`

I changed the code to sort the array as your answer :

`$sheetNames = rsort($objPHPExcel['sitelist']->getSheetNames(), SORT_STRING);
print_r($sheetNames);`

output:

`ErrorException [ Strict ]: Only variables should be passed by reference`

Comment: @hyipscript You first have to save it in a variable, then you can use the function, try it again

Comment: I have chaged the code. Output is showing '1' as a number  only:

`$sheetNamesUnsorted = $objPHPExcel['sitelist']->getSheetNames();
$sheetNames = rsort($sheetNamesUnsorted, SORT_STRING); print_r($sheetNames);`

Output: 1

Comment: @hyipscript Please look at my answer! You don't have to assign the `rsort()` call. Just write: `$sheetNamesUnsorted = $objPHPExcel['sitelist']->getSheetNames(); rsort($sheetNamesUnsorted, SORT_STRING); print_r($sheetNames);`

Comment: You are correct. It is solved now. I got output that I want: `Array ( [0] => Paying [1] => 2015 [2] => 2014 [3] => 2013 )` Thanks a lot.

Comment: Done. I have followed this 'meta' for your answer. Moreover I have been waiting for an answer of my question in wordpress.here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173211. It would be great if you can take a look and give me an idea.